# How to reverse-engineer a USB device without monitoring traffic?

Tags: usb, reverse-engineering

How is it possible to determine the commands to operate a usb device, if that device comes from another operating system and traffic monitoring software cannot be installed on that OS. The only method i can think of is sending random commands to the device, until the device responds, but this seems implausible for more complex commands, and potentially dangerous. For example, consider the DualShock 4 controller. Sony has not made an official driver for this device, so what method can i use to create a linux driver for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a hardware protocol analyzer.  Then you won't need to install any software on the host or device under test.  Here is one that I have used:

http://www.totalphase.com/products/beagle-usb12/